# Deficiency index of symmetric operator is locally constant

Tags: complex-analysis, functional-analysis, operator-theory, quantum-mechanics

Let $A: D_A \rightarrow H$ be a symmetric linear operator defined on $D_A \subseteq H$. Define the deficiency index of $A$ at $z \in \mathbb{C} \setminus \mathbb{R}$ to be $\dim( \ker (A^* - \bar{z}))$. Then I want to show that the deficiency index is constant on the upper half-plane and constant on the lower half-plane.

The assertion is given in Lax, section 33.2, Theorem 3 (i), but he does not prove it.

If $A$ is also closed, then I am able to show that if the deficiency index is $0$ then it is so on the whole half plane, which is a consequence of the fact that the resolvent set is open. However, I don't know about the general case.

Comment: [Kato](https://www.maths.ed.ac.uk/~v1ranick/papers/kato1.pdf) p.270 "since every symmetric
operator is closable, there is no essential restriction in assuming T to be
closed"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The proof is in Reed/Simon “Methods of Modern Mathematicsl Physics”, Vol. 2, Section X:  Theorem X.1